# XML/SQL Query Issue

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

**Question**

Write an SQL command to create a table BookHistory. The table should have a title column to store a string and be a primary key, and a bookDetails column of type XMLType. Write a second SQL command to select the title and, from bookDetails, the XML node ’/author/telephoneNumber’ where the XML node ’/author/surname’ is ‘Chan’.

**Answer/Attempt**

```
CREATE TABLE BookHistory(
title varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
bookDetails XMLType);

SELECT title, XMLQuery(/author/telephoneNumber/text()
PASSING bookDetails RETURNING CONTENT)
FROM BookHistory
WHERE extractValue(bookDetails,'/author/surName') = 'Chan';
```

**Error**
    ORA-00936: missing expression

Can someone explain what am doing wrong. its my first time doing xml/sql.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to your [`XMLQuery()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/functions249.htm), the `XQuery_string`, needs to be quoted:

```
SELECT title, XMLQuery('/author/telephoneNumber/text()' as telephoneNumber
PASSING bookDetails RETURNING CONTENT)
FROM BookHistory
WHERE extractValue(bookDetails,'/author/surName') = 'Chan';
```

That gets rid of your error; and I think it gives the result you want... but as an XMLType still.

You could also do this:

```
SELECT title,
 extractValue(bookDetails, '/author/telephoneNumber') as telephoneNumber
FROM BookHistory
WHERE extractValue(bookDetails,'/author/surName') = 'Chan';
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d5b2/3) of the second version; the first version doesn't error, but doesn't return for some reason in that environment, but both run fine for me under 11.2.0.3 and give the same result; with sample data:

```
insert into bookhistory values ('Some title',
 XMLType('
<author>
 <surName>Chan</surName>
 <telephoneNumber>1234</telephoneNumber>
</author>
'));

insert into bookhistory values ('Another book',
 XMLType('
<author>
 <surName>Segal</surName>
 <telephoneNumber>5678</telephoneNumber>
</author>
'));
```

Both give:

```
TITLE                TELEPHONENUMBER
-------------------- --------------------
Some title           1234
```

But the first version returns an XMLType, which displays as above in SQL*Plus but not in SQLDeveloper; you should really get the actual text value:

```
SELECT title, XMLQuery('/author/telephoneNumber/text()'
PASSING bookDetails RETURNING CONTENT).getStringVal() as telephoneNumber
FROM BookHistory
WHERE extractValue(bookDetails,'/author/surName') = 'Chan';

TITLE                TELEPHONENUMBER    
-------------------- --------------------
Some title           1234
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/73150/2) of both working versions.

Comment: now gives me an error saying :
ORA-04044: procedure, function, package, or type is not allowed here

Comment: @user2993831 - hmm, I don't get an error [on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e9f541/5). But if I try it there with data then it doesn't return, not sure why at all - doesn't error though. Don't have direct access to a DB to test properly, sorry. Can you use `extract` for the phone number instead, though? [Like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d5b2/3)?

Comment: @user2993831 - I don't see how you're getting that error from this code. SQL Fiddle doesn't like the XMLType-returning version, but it just never comes back it doesn't error; and the same code is fine in SQL*Plus/SQL Developer. I've added two alternatives though, both of which seem to work everywhere. Maybe you need to show exactly what you're running now and the full error stack?

Comment: i dont know what am doing wrong but it doesnt work for me at all. Am using oracle sql instant client and i tried it in oracle application express but no luck

Comment: @user2993831 - we can't tell what you're doing wrong either without seeing it. Can you create an SQL Fiddle with exactly what you're running that produces that error? Re you sure it's this query that's erroring, not something you're running afterwards?